# Import excel with leading empty cells removes commas

Tags: excel, ssis, etl

I have a simple excel-file with some data. Some specific columns can be NULL, 0 or have the length of numeric(10,5) like the following format as example: *12345.12345*.

The output column from the excel-source is configured as SSIS-type DT_R8 (double-precision floating-point).
[image: The output column from the excel-source is configured as SSIS-type DT_R8 (double-precision floating-point). Click here for picture.]

This works fine. Some further files got the same format but sometimes the leading rows after the headline are empty [image: the leading rows after the headline are empty. Click here for picture.]

In this case SSIS will import the following rows without commas. They are just removed. *12345.12345* will be *1234512345*.

So I changed the excel-output column to SSIS-type DT_WSTR(50) (this is unicode-text) [image: excel-output column to SSIS-type DT_WSTR(50) (this is unicode-text)] and implemented a conversion-task to DT_R8 again (double precission) [image: conversion-task to DT_R8 again (double precission)]. This works fine for the file with leading empty cells!

But if I import another file without leading empty rows - I will get huge results:

[image]
9,98994 is converted to 9,9894E+16. Another worse example (not shown in this picture): 408,452 will be converted to 408452.

So either I import excel with type DT_R8 (float) and lose commas when importing *empty leadings cells* or I import excel with type DT_WSTR (text) with conversion-task and get huge numbers when importing *without empty leading cells*.

I don't know what bug this is and how to fix it. I tried a lot of data-conversion and tried many data-types. I can't change the excel-file by itself because it is generated automatically and I can not import with a `WHERE COLUMNNAME IS NOT NULL`-condition, because the other columns contains also important data.

EDIT:
Additional infos for the file with leading empty cells: this fileformat is somehow weird what leads to the bug. The first values with 0 are in row 65:
[image]

Float-values just begins with line 1061:
[image].

I think that is just too late and SSIS interpret this column as integer-value with no commas.

Comment: I wonder if part of this is a lack of localization in the tooling? In the US, the comma is the number grouping character and the period signifies decimal digits separator whereas Germany uses the inverse. The other challenge you'll run into is those initial empty columns influence the typing Excel presents to SSIS. Even rules like "always import as DT_WSTR" can lead to problems like a [date in Excel](http://www.debugging.com/bug/19252) might come into the pipeline as the days since 1900-01-01

Comment: Thank you very much for editing my post and giving good tips @billinkc . I answered the solution. What does  [your link](http://www.debugging.com/bug/19252) mean?

Comment: The link _used_ to point to an article and the code remedy for dealing with converting Excel internal number for date to an actual date. Days since 1900-01-01 is not accurate as Excel made the same logic error at Lotus 1-2-3 (the competitor in the early days) https://stackoverflow.com/a/62182403/181965

Answer (score 1, accepted):

billinkc's tips were right! I wouldn't try it without his guesses, but the problem was somehow the country. In the conversion-task I had to replace dots with commas from the input-column:

```
ISNULL(anspr_vk) || LEN(TRIM(anspr_vk)) == 0 ? "0,0" : REPLACE(anspr_vk,".",",")
```

[image]

This took me some time - thank you really much for let me finding the right way, billinkc!