# SSIS package inserting '12/31/1899' instead of '1/1/1900' that was provided

Tags: ssis

SSIS package inserting '12/31/1899' instead of '1/1/1900' that was provided in the excel sheet...why is it changing to another date? This is causing smalldatetime issues in downstream table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because of `Lotus 1-2-3`, which was the prevalent spreadsheet program in the Jurassic Period. `Lotus` was incorrectly coded with the year 1900 being a leap year. It was not, of course, because it was a full century, but that little error was baked in.

When Microsoft introduced `Excel`, they wanted to steal marketshare from `Lotus`, so they built that same error into `Excel` on purpose, so that folks could port their old `1-2-3` spreadsheets over to the spanky new Microsoft product.

So the date that Excel represents internally as `0` is not, actually, January 1, 1900. It's off by one, to account for that non-existent February 29, 1900, and after import that shift shows up in your SQL table as December 31, 1899.

My favorite part of all of this is that somebody did it on purpose.

Luckily, you can change the Excel workbook to encode the dates as you're expecting them by selecting the [Use 1904 data system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system) option in the `Advanced` options. Much more detail on that in the link, though.

You'll have to decide whether fixing the spreadsheet or coding around it in SSIS is less of a bother in your situation.